# Redirect www.*.example.com to *.example.com on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I currently have a catch-all for *.example.com in Apache.

Sometimes people type in www.*.example.com, which fails on the wildcard SSL certificate.

Is there a way to redirect www.*.example.com to *.example.com without any SSL certificate error?

Comment: On port 443, the SSL port.. no.  On port 80, sure, you don't need any certificate.  If you want to make a connection to the SSL port without an error, you need a valid certificate for the hostname being used.

Comment: I hadn't thought for doing it on port 80 but that just might work. How do I redirect from www.*.domain.com:80 to *.domain.com:443?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

Long answer: You need to establish the secure connection (TLS) before you can redirect. Best way I can think of is install LetEncrypt or similar to get some free certs so you can answer requests on https://www.<domain> and from there issue a 308 to https://<domain>